# Delay in receiving GCM messages

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Hi Iam using GCM API in my android application I manage to send and receid gve messages from my localhost web server (apache) but I receive them with big delay (25-75 seconds).

I tried solution referenced http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html 
and set my ttl to 0 and delay_while_idle to true in my php script.

```
 $post = array(
                    'delay_while_idle' => true,
                    'registration_ids'  => $ids,
                    'data'              => $data,
                    'time_to_live' => 0,
                    );
```

But it doesn't change anything.I searched  stackoverflow for solution but didn't found anything concrete.

I managed to resolve problem i set my thread sleep time to from 5000 to 100 and I received messages immediatly.

Comment: The delay may be caused by network connectivity issues. Is your phone connected via WiFi or mobile data connection?

Comment: Iam using genymotion emulator on my notebook which is connected to wireless network.